# Why $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ is not free as $\mathbb Z$-module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

1) Why $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ is not free as a $\mathbb Z$-module ? Indeed, let $1=1\cdot 1$ and thus $\{1\}$ is a basis, no ?

2) Does $\mathbb Z$ is a free $\mathbb Z$-module ? I would say yes with basis $\{1\}$, but since $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ is not free, I have doubt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) No: $1$ is not free (linearly independent), since $2\cdot 1=0$.

2): Yes: $\mathbf Z$ is a free $\mathbf Z$-module of rank one.

Comment: What do you mean by saying that 1 itself (as opposed to a subgroup, etc.) is free?

Comment: Linearly independent, as a system of (one) vector.

Comment: Free (abelian) is not equivalent to linearly independent (though the implication is fine in one direction); take a direct product of infinitely many copies of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: We speak of free modules when they have a basis. The direct product of infinitely many copies of **Z** is not free, only their direct sum. Aren't you confusing ‘free’ and ‘torsion-free’?

Comment: No, that's my point: That direct product is not free, though any finite-dimensional (over Q) subspace of it is free and admits a basis.

Comment: I still don't understand your objection. We also speak of a free system of vectors to mean they're linearly independent  Your example shows a direct limit of free abelian groups (or free modules) is not free. All this is well known, since in particular any flat module is a direct limit of finitely generated free modules.

Comment: Of course direct limits don't preserve freeness. My point is that linear independence-- that is, f.g. submodules are free--- is not equivalent to freeness (over Z). But this is going nowhere, and the OP was a very simple question.

Answer (score 3):

It is true that $\{1\}$ is a *generating set* (or a *set of generators*, if you prefer that phrase), but it is not a basis. In order to be a basis, every element in the module must be given by a *unique* linear combination of basis elements, and that's not the case here. For instance, $1\cdot1$ and $3\cdot1$ are two different linear combinations that give the same element in $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$.

$\Bbb Z$, on the other hand, *is* a free $\Bbb Z$-module. That's because $\{1\}$ is a basis in this case. Indeed, if $n\cdot1=m\cdot1$, then $n=m$.

Answer (score 1):

My addition, there is a universal property for free objects.

Let $S$ mark the set that generates the free object $F$ in question, then there is a set function (not homomorphism) $\imath:S\to F$. For this free object it is such that if we have a set function $f:S\to M$, where $M$ is another algebraic object of the desired type, then there exist a homomorphism $g$ such that $g\circ\imath = f$. For $\Bbb Z_2$ we have, as you said, $S=\{1\}$, now let $M=\Bbb Z$, then if $\Bbb Z_2$ is free we should have a homomorphism $\varphi$ such that it commutes, however the only homomorphism between $\Bbb Z_2$ and $\Bbb Z$ is the zero homomorphism, as such we have $\varphi\circ\imath(1)=0$ but $f(1)=1$ and as such it cannot be free.

For the other it follows equivalently.